# How can I know the AT-Command that suit my modem?

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, modem

I have A Samsung Galaxy Win Duos mobile and I'm using `AT Command` terminal on it. I tried several `AT-Commands` some got me the answer and some didn't.

As an example of commands that worked:`AT`and `AT+CSQ`

but a lot of commands didn't work like:`AT!GSMINFO?`

I want to know the commands that's suit my modem.

I tried `AT+CLAC` but it didn't work at all.(That's mean the program stopped)

I entered`ATI` to know the kind of modem and it got me:

```
Manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
Model:        4086
Revision:     8x25Q-QSOSKOLYM-3030 1 [Jan 29 2013 07:00:00]
IMEI:         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
+GCAP:        +CGSM,+FCLASS,+DS
```

Could you get me these command or help me to find a way for knowing them

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a Gobi modem. There are Gobi2000,3000, and 4000 modems though. On Qualcomms developer website you can sign up and grab some documentation.

Comment: Is this question still open, or was it answered in chat?

Comment: @SList Still open. This modem is built into a mobile phone so from my side it's guess work. From the chat we pretty went into the direction of assuming that it has a limited AT Command set based upon Gobi.

Comment: With Qualcomm, it's either available online (there is a manual from 2011), or else it's proprietary and deadly secret.  So I don't think anyone can really add anything to that, surely?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the standardized AT commands in the 3GPP spec [here](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm). Most modem manufacturers will add their own AT commands in addition to the 3GPP specification. Some manufacturers will give just about anybody a copy of their AT commands, some will not give it away without an NDA. You might also try joining the "developer program" at your manufacturer's website, assuming they have a developer program.